# How to prove this identity? (Perhaps related to partition)

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions, partitions

How to prove this identity?
$ \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{x^{n^2}}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n)}= \frac{1}{\prod_{k \ge 0}(1-x^{5k+1})(1-x^{5k+4})}$
I will appreciate it a lot if a solution using method involving generating functions.

Comment: This are the famous Rogers-Ramanujan identities. You will find plenty information in the internet.